# validate a numerical value with Robotframework/Python

Tags: python, eclipse, robotframework

i'm trying to validate whether a numerical value somewhere on a page is between 0 and 40 max for my robotframework/python test using Eclipse.

- the piece of text that states 'X workitems..' is located within a message/status bar-like component on the bottom of the page, seen below:

[image: screenshot]

What is the best practise in handling such scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Get Text command or something similar to pull out the string.  You will then need to use the String library to retrieve the substring you are looking for, then assert that against your expectations.

That said, the above will be brittle in my view and doesn't sound great approach.  Can you get the dev team to output the number you want as an attribute of the element it is part of or somewhere more accessible in general?

Comment: i will try that approach. but it's a standard implementation of IBM Case Manager/Filenet so not sure if i can get it as an attribute.. thanks

Comment: your question lacks a lot of detail to be honest, more detail will help the quality of answers.  Will this number be equal to the row count in the table?  If so perhaps counting the rows is a better approach?